# Why files are not being uploaded in the back-end from react-front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload

Recently I started working on a project where I am using react as my front-end and node as my back-end. In this project, I have a requirement to upload multiple images from the front-end and my back-end will receive the files and they will be uploaded in cloudinary. I have created an API route for that. Which works just fine! but when I am trying to do that same thing from my react front-end, I am not receiving any files just getting an empty [] but when I was using postman, I was receiving all the files properly inside an array. What is the issue here? I guess this is a problem from my front-end. But I can't figure out what is the problem.

I am sharing my front-end and back-end code:-

**front-end**

```js
const Upload = () => {
const [fileAra, setFileAra] = useState([]);

// for sending these files to the back-end
async function uploadProduct() {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("assets", fileAra);

      const res = await fetch("/get_product/post_product", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });

      const body = await res.json();

      if (res.status === 200) {
        history.push(`/profile/${user._id}`);
        toast.dark(body.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

    return (
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={(e) => setFileAra(e.target.files)} />
        <button onClick={uploadProduct}></button>
    )
}
```

**Back-end route**

```js
router.post(
  "/post_product",
  checkAuth,
  multer.array("assets", 10),
  async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const pictureFiles = req.files;

      // map through images and create a promise array using cloudinary upload function
      const multiplePicturePromise = pictureFiles.map((picture) =>
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(picture.path, {
          folder: `devR-Commerce/products/${req.user.name}`,
        })
      );

      const imageResponses = await Promise.all(multiplePicturePromise);

      // separating each of the images into objects
      const allImagesSeparatedInObject = imageResponses.map((img) => ({
        photoId: img.public_id,
        photoUrl: img.secure_url,
      }));

      // creating a new product instance
      const newProduct = new Product({
        user: req.user._id,
        images: allImagesSeparatedInObject,
      });

      // saving the product in my database
      const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();

      // creating relation between these two collections: Product and User
      await User.updateOne(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $push: { products: savedProduct._id } }
      );

      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "Product uploaded successfully", newProduct });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  },
);
```

Note: The back-end route works properly I have tested with Postman. But when I try to send the same files from my front-end, I don't receive any files. Might be a problem in the front-end. Please help me if you know the answer. If you need any additional information about this problem, please feel free to ask. Thanks for checking this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append each file to the FormData one by one and not attach the whole array at once, like this.

```
async function uploadProduct() {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();

      for (let i = 0; i < fileAra.length; i++) {
         formData.append(fileAra[i].name, fileAra[i])
      }

      const res = await fetch("/get_product/post_product", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });

      const body = await res.json();

      if (res.status === 200) {
        history.push(`/profile/${user._id}`);
        toast.dark(body.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

you can check out this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/formdata-explained/) explaining FormData for further details